# How to except some machines in azure pipeline pool?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an azure pipeline like following:

```
target:
- main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
      name: APool
    steps
      -script: ....
  - job: B1
    pool: 
      name: APool
    steps
      -script: ....
```

So my APool has 8 linux machines and some 2 of them (m1, m2 machines) has not instaled docker yet.
How can I except these from pool in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You may use demands: [Specify demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

1. Add a custom capability on your agents:

[image]

2. Then use it in the yaml pool definition:

   ```
    pool:
      name: MyPool
      demands:
      - myCustomCapability   # exists check for myCustomCapability
   ```

Comment: can not I add any demand in pipeline.yaml?